# How to get details of the inserted row from sqlite, android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a table (Detail) with two columns one column (ID) is primary and auto-increment while the other column (EmpName) is varchar type. While inserting data in database i am only inserting data in EmpName column using the following code. But I want to know the details of that record (ID and name but i know only name and ID is created by database). I can write another select statement and get the last record of the cursor after executing the insert query but  if another insertion will be done before executing the select statements then my database will give me wrong result. How can i get the details?

```
ContentValues initialvalues = new ContentValues();
initialvalues.put("EmpName", "John");
db.insert("Detail", null, initialvalues);// db is database
```

The above code is working fine for insertion of data in database but How to get that details?

Comment: simply use query or rawquery methods of Sqlitedatabase class.

Comment: How to use rawquery in this case. do you have any sample example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please the API:SQLiteStatement.executeInsert()

According to the source code:

```
/**
     * Execute this SQL statement and return the ID of the row inserted due to this call.
     * The SQL statement should be an INSERT for this to be a useful call.
     *
     * @return the row ID of the last row inserted, if this insert is successful. -1 otherwise.
     *
     * @throws android.database.SQLException If the SQL string is invalid for
     *         some reason
     */
    public long executeInsert() {
        BlockGuard.getThreadPolicy().onWriteToDisk();
        if (!mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("database " + mDatabase.getPath() + " already closed");
        }
        long timeStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        mDatabase.lock();

        acquireReference();
        try {
            native_execute();
            mDatabase.logTimeStat(mSql, timeStart);
            return (mDatabase.lastChangeCount() > 0) ? mDatabase.lastInsertRow() : -1;
        } finally {
            releaseReference();
            mDatabase.unlock();
        }
    }
```